# How make to get tests to pass reliably when run together as a suite?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running the selenium scripts in batches and getting failures, but if I run the test cases individually they pass. All the test cases are supposedly independent of each other.

Comment: Have you analyzed the error messages? What's in there?

Answer (score 3):

This usually indicates that you either have dependencies between tests or you have data storage that doesn't get reset and affects other tests.

Work to make sure that tests are completely independent from each other and use a database that gets reset between tests.  Initially this will seem hard/impossible but with enough effort it is achievable and wonderful.